# Need to recover MYSQL data

Tags: mysql, database-restore

An important table in one of my clients databases has been totally corrupted. All of our backups are woefully out of date. Is there any sort of restore point or something? Does IIS have any restore points?

EDIT: Excuse me, not corrupted, overwritten. Bytewise it's fine, values just overwritten with garbage data.

Comment: We are rebuilding the data from other sources, should take no longer than a day. Lesson learned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried [REPAIR TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/repair-table.html)? If so, then you are probably out of luck.  IIS doesn't backup MySQL data, nor does MySQL do it on its own.  So, if your only backups are outdated, you may be up the creek.